# Type 'java.util.EventListener' does not have type parameters

Tags: java

I want to read the comments posted on Fireestore in real-time.
To do this, I used EventListner to add it to the `readComment()`
This error("Type '`java.util.EventListener`' does not have type parameters") appears in QuerySnapshot in the `.addSnapshotListner(new EventListner<QuerySnapshot>(){`

And there's an error on `@Override`.
I used this code to posted on Firestore in real-time

```
db.collection("comments")
                .whereEqualTo("postid", writeinfo.getPostid())
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            switch (dc.getType()) {
                                case ADDED:
                                    Log.d(TAG, "New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                    break;
                                case MODIFIED:
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                    break;
                                case REMOVED:
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
```

and this is my `readComment()`

```
readComment(){
 db.collection("comments")
            .whereEqualTo("postid", writeinfo.getPostid())
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) { 
                        final ArrayList<CommentInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            arrayList.add(document.toObject(CommentInfo.class));
                        }
                        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(ViewPostActivity.this);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
                        commentAdapter=new CommentListAdapter(arrayList,ViewPostActivity.this);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
                        commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error => ", task.getException());
                    }
                }

            });
}
```

Comment: You `import`ed the wrong `EventListener`.

Comment: How can I import correct EventListner ?? I bring EventListner code in Firestore homepage

Comment: The duplicate shows you the correct import.